# There is a problem with following the agent from a 3D perspective

Tags: anylogic

I set the 3D perspective to follow the vehicle after it starts running, but the picture is very strange. It seems like the camera is placed in a very far place.
[3d view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EZvB.png)

The normal viewing angle should be from behind the vehicle
[carcamera set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLaHy.png)

Comment: maybe this can help? 
https://noorjax.com/2022/01/25/blog-camera-on-agent/

Comment: show properties of the camera as well :)

Answer (score 0):

When you set the 3D window to use the camera located on the agent you must also set the follow camera to true.

[image]

You can check out this model on the AnyLogic cloud and also download the source file to see how it is done - https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/b301b4cd-f619-4c66-8a40-0a10172544f4?mode=SETTINGS